# Trying to create a simple Tabulator Ajax Grid

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, tabulator

I have downloaded and installed the proper parts to use tabulator I got an example to show.
Now I'm trying to pull data from my localhost database to use for a simple Ajax grid.

Here is the PHP code I'm using in a file called query.php

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'PASS');
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}


$result = $db->query($db, "SELECT * FROM dataBase.table;");
if ($result) {
    $to_encode = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $to_encode[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($to_encode);
}
```

And this is my HTML for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Bitnami: Open Source. Simplified</title>
    <link href="bitnami.css" media="all" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabulator/dist/js/tabulator.min.js">
</script>
<div id="example-table">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON('query.php', function (data) {
            var mydata = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("#example-table").tabulator("setData", mydata);
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, I'm getting a blank page let me know if you have any advice.

Comment: for starters need to check if `$.getJSON` callback gets triggered. If it does copy the json and see if the plugin works just passing in the data without ajax. If the callback doesn't get triggered add some error handling. Without some basic troubleshooting info there are too many unknowns

Comment: Also check browser console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to get the JSON yourself, Tabulator will do that for you:

`$("#example-table").tabulator("setData", "query.php");`